# Is there a classical Latin verb for furnishing?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, word-request, verbs, finnish

I recently read a booklet called "Wolmar Schildt — sata uudissanaa" which is built around a list of a hundred neologisms by Wolmar Schildt (1810–1893), one of the most active promoters of Finnish language of his era.
Among these neologisms (in addition to the word "neologism" itself, "uudissana") is the verb "sisustaa".
Translations are provided to a couple of languages, and in English it is aptly rendered as "furnish", in the sense of placing furniture in an apartment.

The Latin translation provided is *instruere*, but I'm not convinced.
[Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=instruo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) give "furnish" in the sense of preparation, not in the sense of interior decoration, unless I'm mistaken.
Is there a classical Latin verb (perhaps supported by a noun or two) for furnishing which is attested in the sense of interior decoration or acquisition of furniture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Instruo* is perfectly all right. An alternative is *orno*, or a derivative (*exorno, adorno*), similar in meaning to *instruo*, 'to fit out or 'equip', though it lacks the latter's notion of 'set in order'. Cicero (Verr. II, 2, 84) has *. . . . angebatur animi necessario quod domum eius exornatam et instructam . . . .*, which is a bit like 'having your cake and eating it', as we say.

Otherwise, the general word for furniture in this context, *sc*. the permanent, physical stuff — 'goods and chattels' is the English expression — is *supellex, -ectilis*. You might feel more comfortable in writing *supellectilem instruere* or *ponere* if you need to exclude the idea of decoration implied by *orno*.